How to best handle badly concatenated json
I receive a single json file from a client which is not correct. The client concatenates multiple json resposnses into one file:
{
    object1
    {
        ...
    }
}   
{
    object2
    {
        ...
    }
}
...

When I parse it with dataframe in pyspark, I always get a count of only one root object which is correct, because it reads only the first object and doesn't care about the rest. 
I need to somehow handle this and I'm trying to figure out what is the best way performance wise?
Can dataframe handle bad jsons or can I easily fix this with python?

"The client concatenates multiple json resposnses into one file" - Can the client be modified to produce valid JSON?

He will have to, I need a temporary solution for now

Tools like jq can be used to turn a stream of objects into a single list. For example,  echo '{"foo": 1} {"bar": 2}' | jq -s produces [{"foo": 1}, {"bar": 2}].

Are the actual json records one per line or is it formatted like you have. Personally I think I would rather get jsonlines than an actual list of json records.

You can use the jq module to parse the data.
>>> data = open("tmp.json").read()
>>> data
'{"foo": 1}\n{"bar": 2}\n'
>>> import jq
>>> jq.compile(".").input_text(data).all()
[{'foo': 1}, {'bar': 2}]

What you have isn't really invalid or incorrect; it's just a stream of individual JSON objects rather than a single JSON value like an array.

Thanks! That worked and you guided me into what I was actually dealing with. I didn't know streaming individual jsons was a thing.
